# Linear ALgebra Subspaces over sets

Tags: linear-algebra

Let  $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$ and $M,N ≤ V$. Consider the following subsets of $V$:
(a) $M \cup N$
  (b) $M \cap N$
    (c) $M+N$
  (d) $M - N$
For each of the subsets in (a)-(d) above, either prove that it is a subspace of $V$ or give a counterexample to show that it need not to be a subspace of $V$.

Comment: I dont know what is the Latex

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

For d) notice that $0\not\in M\setminus N$ and for a) prove that $M\cup N$ is a subspace if and only if $M\subset N$ or $N\subset M $. Finally for the other cases prove using the definition that they are subspace of $V$.